# How do I find which country has the lowest average time to finish a marathon?

Tags: r

I have a data set with a column of countries and a column of time it took them to run a marathon. I want to find out which 5 countries completed it in the shortest time on average. I am new to R so only have basic knowledge. The column of time is in hours. eexample of the data: marathon$Countries is a column of the nationality of each runner, marathon$OverallHrs is the overall time it took to complete the marathon for each runner.

I have tried

```
tapply(marathon$OverallHrs, marathon$Country, mean)
```

It hasnt worked in the way I want it to

Comment: Is "marathon" a well known dataset? It doesn't seem to be in my preloaded datasets (seen by running ```data()```. You should add a sample of data to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are not referring to the trivial case where you don't have repeated countries for your "country" column. For a beginner in R, i would strongly encourage to start learning with the package "tidyverse".

Below is the solution, where you can have repeated countries for the column "Country"

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
# Generate 10 Countries, each one 5 times
A = sample(rep(1:10,5))
# Generate 50 random timing from (5-20)
B = round(runif(50)*15 + 5)

#Create a dataframe with columns (Country, Timing), rows = 50
df = data.frame("Country" = paste0("Country",A),
                "Timing" = B)

#Dataframe will look like this
# Country Timing
# 1  Country5     15
# 2  Country4     17
# 3  Country4      5
# 4  Country3     12
# 5  Country5     16

# Calculate average marathon timing
df_mean <- df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>% #Group
  summarise(Mean_Timing = mean(Timing), .groups = 'drop') %>% #Calculate Mean_Timing
  arrange(Mean_Timing) # Arrange by fastest timing first


#Dataframe = df_mean
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Country   Mean_Timing
# <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 Country9         10.6
# 2 Country1         11.4
# 3 Country3         11.4
# 4 Country4         11.4
# 5 Country2         12.2
# 6 Country10        12.6
# 7 Country8         13.2
# 8 Country7         13.6
# 9 Country5         15  
# 10 Country6         15.2

#To get the first 5 country, would just be
df_mean$Country[1:5]
# "Country9" "Country1" "Country3" "Country4" "Country2"
```

There is always the aggregate function in R for calculating mean per group. Lesser code, but I still prefer the tidyverse method as it is intuitive to use after a while and can be tweaked slightly to solve any dataframe question.
Anyway, here is the solution using aggregate.

```
df_mean2 <- aggregate(df[, 2], list(df$Country), mean) # Calculate Mean
df_mean2[order(df_mean2$x), ] # Sort by ascending
     Group.1    x
10  Country9 10.6
1   Country1 11.4
4   Country3 11.4
5   Country4 11.4
3   Country2 12.2
2  Country10 12.6
9   Country8 13.2
8   Country7 13.6
6   Country5 15.0
7   Country6 15.2
```

Comment: Thank you Andy! Are you able to help me plot these results on a Histogram? With those countries on the bottom and their mean values on the y axis?

Comment: @DavidWall i think what u mean is a bar chart, rather than a histogram. You only have 1 variable for a histogram. Most people have their preferences on customizing their bar chart, you can start from here http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization#create-barplots .